# send restful request by Jmeter

Tags: apache, xmlhttprequest, jmeter, load, restful-url

I have a restful request and I need to send it to a webservice using Jmeter.
here is my reuest:

```
{"type":"CustomerProfileReqModel","messageCode":"GetCustRq","messageVersion":"V1.0","language":"en-gb","recieverCode":"newone","customerModel":{"userName":"load24","password":"P@ssw0rd","categoryCode":"NORM"},"uiCacheVersion":"3e096b72-ed40-4f8a-aad3-9ed52a4aa8ba"}
```

And here is what I created in JMeter:

Thread Group
SOAP/XML-RPC Request
URL:http://localhost:9000/MyFawryWeb/rest/MFServlet/service

When I run I got the below error:

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException: The server 11.92.0.91 failed to respond
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1976)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.SoapSampler.sample(SoapSampler.java:271)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for sending REST requests, the JSON payload needs to go into "Body Data" tab like:

   [image: JMeter REST Request]
2. I believe you should also be adding a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of `application/json`
3. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details and run your request (don't forget to remove it when it comes to running load test with increased number of users)

See [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) for more information and detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped a lot